# Move branch to another branch

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I have started doing some work on a branch which I have in term realised was the wrong branch. Is there a way to move a branch to a different branch.

For example:

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- HEAD
 \-- E -- F -- G -- H -- I -- J
      \-- K -- L
```

And I want this:

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- HEAD
 \    \-- K -- L
  \
   \-- E -- F -- G -- H -- I -- J
```

Comment: Please mark the best (in your opinion) answer as "Accepted" if you find it solving your problem! :-)

Comment: Suggestion: reduce your illustration: EFGHIJ is not necessary. EF would be enough.

Answer (score 98):

Let's say you've named your branches like so:

```
    A -- B -- C -- D (master)
     \-- E -- G -- H -- I -- J (current-parent)
          \-- K -- L (my-branch)
```

What you want to do is rebase `my-branch` onto the B commit like so:

```
    git rebase current-parent my-branch --onto B
```

Comment: This answer should have been accepted ! Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks for the pretty picture

Comment: the `--onto B`, where `B` is a commit, can also use a branch name, if you want to rebase to the tip of that branch.

Comment: @colm.anseo if you want to rebase to the tip of a branch (eg. master), you wouldn't need `--onto` anymore, right? You would just do `git checkout my-branch && git rebase master`. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 33):

You could use `git rebase --onto`, e.g.,

```
git rebase --onto new-base old-base your-branch
```

So in your case, something like:

```
git rebase --onto B E L
```

should work.

Comment: thank you for naming the options.  Very confused until seeing this.

Answer (score 2):

This is just the sort of thing `git rebase` can do.

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html