# Moving Branch from Master to Another Branch in Git

Tags: git

I usually use subversion, and am getting used to git.

I cloned a copy of a remote repository to my localhost, and then created a new branch, which we'll call "myNewBranch'.  However, I created that branch off of master when it should have been a sub-branch of "DEVELOPMENT".

Here are the steps I took:

1. git clone remoteURL localhost
2. git checkout -b mynewBranch (should
   have switched to DEVELOPMENT first)
3. git add {whatever files I
   changed}
4. git commit
5. git push origin myNewBranch

Here is what the hierarchy **should** look like:

Master
---> DEVELOPMENT
  ---> myNewBranch

Here is what it *currently* looks like:
Master--->myNewBranch

How can I rectify this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply rebase your new branch on top of development.

```
git checkout myNewBranch
git rebase development
```

Comment: This deserves a little more information: Given that **development** branch is set up **on top** or master (and assuming master hasn't diverged from development), then you can you rebase as @Igal said.

Comment: @eftshift0, thanks for the help. Sorry to sound like a total noob here (I am, been reading through documentation to get better), but won't this will take all the changes made for myNewBranch and incorporate any changes made in master?  Does this actually remove the myNewBranch branch from master?  Is the goal here to allow me to checkout a copy of my branch with any additional changes and the to commit under DEVELOPMENT?

Comment: I don't want to understand what you mean with all your questions so this is my brief explanation of what's going on. Rebase, as the name implies, means to move the base of a revision or chain of revisions to be based on another point in history. You started your feature branch from _master_ instead of _development_, you want to move the base of that little branch from master to development..... by running `git rebase development` you are asking git to move your 1 (or x) revisions that belong to your branch and that are _not_ part of the history of development to be moved on top of development.

Comment: master won't move... development won't move either. It's only your branch that will move.

Comment: @eftshift0: Thanks for the clarification, that makes more sense.  I guess I got a bit confused because the answer stated to "rebase master", but it sounds like I want to run "rebase development" to move my branch to development.

Comment: Also, to anyone else that might stumble upon this question, I found another SO question that gives more details:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21459197/move-branch-to-another-branch

Answer (score 1):

I accepted Igal S.'s answer, however instead of rebase I used cherry-pick.

I had a single commit, and my commit was the very last one, so I checked out DEVELOPMENT into a new branch:

```
git checkout -b myNewBranch DEVELOPMENT
```

And then ran cherry-pick on my commit (had to get the hex checksum)

```
git cherry-pick <hex checksum>
```

And then reconciled conflicts.

After that, I commited changes from cherry pick, and then deleted my old branch on both local and master.  I'm still new to git, so don't take my word on this as a solution, but if might be helpful if other people run into the same problem.